# ELK reindex data stream in place

Tags: elasticsearch

I've created a bunch of data streams with the ELK stack but [the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/data-streams-change-mappings-and-settings.html#data-streams-use-reindex-to-change-mappings-settings) only talks about reindexing to a new data stream name. I want to keep my old data stream name. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

that's a limitation of the concept as it's intended to be append only, so you cannot reuse the old datastream name. you could reindex, delete the old stream, and then add an alias that was the original datastream name to the new datastream

(also try not to use `master` documentation, as it's for unreleased branches. you are better off using `current`)

Comment: I ended up reindexing to a new data stream name then reindexing back to the old name. (I'm under the impression logstash can only write to a data stream by name and not by wildcard.)

Comment: that's another way to get around it! :)